# How to get a redditors most down voted comment using PRAW?

Tags: python, praw

Is there a way to get a redditors worst comment using praw?
I  have tried `redditor.get_comments(sort="worst").next().body` with different sorts but nothing produces the desired result. I suppose I could get all their comments and then loop through them but that seems silly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late, but probably the best way to do this is to sort by top, then use `after=t1_d9pvq54` (for example) and a high count to quickly page through the comments until you get to the last one which will be the worst comment.

Answer (score 0):

The sorting types available in PRAW are equivalent to those available on the webinterface, such as 'new', 'top' or 'controversial'. There isn't a special sort to retrieve worst comments. It may be silly to loop through all of them, but that's the only way to do what you want.